# Oracle SQL. Selecting the MAX(Date)

Tags: sql, oracle

Need to update values in a table. Essentially I have added a fromDate and toDate columns. The values I am setting at thepriceDate with:

`UPDATE schema.myTable 
SET FROMDATE = PRICEDATE, TODATE = PRICEDATE 
WHERE FROMDATE IS NULL AND TODATE IS NULL`

This works. I then need to set the latest date to 6000-01-01. All the rows are unique but can relate to similar objects. So I may have:

`priceDate   | fromDate   | toDate     |  INSTRUMENT    | uniqueID
 25/09/2018    25/09/2018   25/09/2018       AUD        |    1
 26/09/2018    26/09/2018   26/09/2018       EUR        |    2
 25/09/2018    25/09/2018   25/09/2018       EUR        |    3
 25/09/2018    25/09/2018   25/09/2018       JPN        |    4
 29/09/2018    29/09/2018   29/09/2018       EUR        |    5 
 29/09/2018    29/09/2018   29/09/2018       JPN        |    6
 20/09/2018    20/09/2018   20/09/2018       JPN        |    7
 28/09/2018    28/09/2018   28/09/2018       AUD        |    8`

I have tried: 
`UPDATE schema.myTable 
SET TODATE = TO_DATE('60000101', 'yyyymmdd') 
WHERE TODATE in ( SELECT MAX(TODATE) FROM schema.myTable WHERE HISTTYPE = 'Close' GROUP BY INSTRUMENT );`

But that gives me multiple of the same Instrument where I only want one of each.
EDIT:

So after my Query I want:

`priceDate   | fromDate   | toDate     |  INSTRUMENT    | uniqueID
 25/09/2018    25/09/2018   25/09/2018       AUD        |    1
 26/09/2018    26/09/2018   26/09/2018       EUR        |    2
 25/09/2018    25/09/2018   25/09/2018       EUR        |    3
 25/09/2018    25/09/2018   25/09/2018       JPN        |    4
 29/09/2018    29/09/2018   01/01/6000       EUR        |    5 
 29/09/2018    29/09/2018   01/01/6000       JPN        |    6
 20/09/2018    20/09/2018   20/09/2018       JPN        |    7
 28/09/2018    28/09/2018   01/01/6000       AUD        |    8`

Comment: you used group by  INSTRUMENT so it will update all max date of each INSTRUMENT group

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @Zaynul-Abadin-Tuhin. Yes. I only want the latest date to update to 01/01/6000 for each Instrument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE schema.myTable t
    SET TODATE = TO_DATE('60000101', 'yyyymmdd') 
    WHERE TODATE = ( SELECT MAX(tt.TODATE)
                     FROM schema.myTable tt
                     WHERE tt.HISTTYPE = 'Close' AND
                           tt.INSTRUMENT = t.INSTRUMENT
                   );
```

Answer (score 0):

If understand correctly then you can use `row_number` window function and find max date of per group of INSTRUMENT then update those

```
SET TODATE = TO_DATE('60000101', 'yyyymmdd') 
WHERE TODATE in ( 
select TODATE from
(
SELECT TODATE ,row_number() over(partition by INSTRUMENT order by TODATE desc) as rn FROM schema.myTable WHERE HISTTYPE = 'Close'
) as t where t.rn=1
 );
```